# SQL query and for loops

Tags: mysql

I need a bit of help with a MySQL query. Right now I have a table that has 3 columns: location, street, and number. I want to write a query whose pseudocode would be...

- for each location:
- for each of the streets of a location
- find the next biggest number

I feel like I am still thinking in "for-loop" logic, but that doesn't really seem to be the way MySQL operates, and it is tripping me up. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Also the primary key is the location-street combo

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want the highest number of each street in each location?

```
SELECT
    location,
    street,
    MAX(number)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    location,
    street
```

First of all, `GROUP BY` aggregates ("*collapses*") rows, so that only one row per location and street will be returned. In the list of rows to return, we then explicitly specify we want the highest number (`MAX()`) instead of the first one that would show up.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

---

If it helps, you can think of a `SELECT` query (albeit very crudely) as filter rules for a loop that goes through every row of the entire table. In these "filter rules" you specify precisely what you want and how you want it, MySQL will then iterate over the entire table and handpick exactly the data you asked for.